# Why can't I play sound when a button is pressed?

Tags: swift, xcode, audio, playsound

This is the code I have written but I am to new to understand how to fix this error. Every time I run the app the build is successful, but then when I go to tap on the button/key, it gives me this error.

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var player: AVAudioPlayer!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func keyAPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        playSound()
    }
    func playSound() {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "C", withExtension: "wav")
        player = try! AVAudioPlayer (contentsOf: url!)
        player.play()
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you set the `AVAudioSession` category?

Comment: The exclamation mark ! tells the compile that you _want_ this crash to happen. I suggest you learn to use the debugger. And how to set breakpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because the `url` doesn't exist.

Check whether you specified the correct file name and wrap the play function in `do` block to catch any other errors. The following code worked without any errors.

```
func playSound() {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "C", withExtension: "wav") else {
        print("File not found")
        return
    }
    do {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        player.play()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Now it is just printing file not found file not found, and then when I fixed that problem it wont play any sound

Comment: How did you fix that problem and what is the name your audio file?

Comment: never mind I didnt fix either problem. thought i did but i didnt. it still only will print file not found and it also will not play any sound

Comment: Make sure you have added the audio file named `C.wav` into the project. The error clearly says such a file doesn't exist in your project folder.